# Who firstly creates Class<?> object during class-loading process?

Tags: java, classloader

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) I found:

> Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual
>   Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method
>   in the class loader.

I checked [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#ClassLoader.compareCerts%28java.security.cert.Certificate%5B%5D%2Cjava.security.cert.Certificate%5B%5D%29), but didn't find the place `defineClass` to be called e.g. from loadClass method.
Could you show me, please, who and when call `defineClass` method according to this scheme:

[image: scheme]

*Picture [source](http://www.techjava.de/topics/2008/01/java-class-loading/)*

Comment: When you're dealing with JVM internals (magic!), a good suspicion is that things are happening in native code (C/C++/asm).

Comment: Sure it could be, but the question is: when does it(Class object appears) happen? The implementation language doesn't matter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `defineClass()` method is called during the invocation of `ClassLoader#loadClass()`. However, this is not directly done within the `java.lang.ClassLoader` class but in one of its subclasses, e.g. in `URLClassLoader#findClass()`.

The call to `ClassLoader#defineClass()` ends up in a call to one of the *native* methods [`defineClass1()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ClassLoader.java?av=f#857) or [`defineClass2()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ClassLoader.java?av=f#860). The C implementations of these methods can be found in OpenJDK in [`src/share/native/java/lang/ClassLoader.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/java/lang/ClassLoader.c).

Answer (score 5):

`java.lang.ClassLoader` is such a big class. Using your GrepCode link (*which is for java 6-b14 version*) you can find at line 267 the public `loadClass`method.

This method, calls a protected `loadClass`method at line 308 and this method try to load a previosly loaded class using:

- `findLoadedClass` which in the ends calls Native methods,
- Calling `parent.loadClass`,
- `findBootstrapClass0` (*a native method also*) if there is no `parent`,
- And finally `findClass` if no class is found.

This is important to say, because `ClassLoader` tries to reuse already loaded clases, keep in mind.

But, where is `defineClass` invoked? No place from this abstract class, but if you use reference tool from GrepCode and search where it is used `defineClass` ([see here results](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root@jdk%24openjdk@6-b14@java%24lang@ClassLoader@defineClass%28java.lang.String%2Cbyte[]%2Cint%2Cint%29&k=u)) you will find a lot of concrete classes which in the end calls `definClass`.

It is not straightforward, some of these classes, override `defineClass` while others calls its own `loadClass` which then calls ... and so on, but finally it calls `defineClass`.

Don't forget that `defineClass` of `ClassLoader` ends in one of three native methods that are responsible of *JVM magic*: `defineClass0`, `defineClass1` and/or `defineClass2`

## Edit

Native function `defineClass0` calls `Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_defineClass0` from `ClassLoader.c`and the same for 1 and 2 functions.

This functions creates the required class using `JVM_DefineClassWithSource` defined in `jvm.h` and implemented in `openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp`.

This last file defines `jvm_define_class_common` function which in the end is the function that creates the required class. Finally, this function calls `JNIHandles::make_local` to allocate the class. You can see the code of this last function in `openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\jniHandles.cpp`

Hope it answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class NetworkClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
         String host;
         int port;

         public Class findClass(String name) {
             byte[] b = loadClassData(name);
             return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
         }

         private byte[] loadClassData(String name) {
             // load the class data from the connection
              . . .
         }
     }
```

Comment: This is the extract fomr Oracle dosumentation.defineClass is a method of ClassLoader which converts an array of bytes into an instance of class Class.
I hope it helps